# Programatically clean the recycle bin With managed Code

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.5, recycle-bin

I'm interested to know is there any recent implementation within latest frameworks to clean the recycle bin.

Old threads has a solution using unmanaged code with `Shell32 dll SHEmptyRecycleBin method.`

I'm not sure about the performance point of view using unmanaged code, since performance in my application is critical so looking this piece of code with a managed solutions..

Then peace of mind for memory leaks etc.....

Comment: How performance critical is it really to clean the recycle bin? Just how often are you going to be doing it? There aren't any managed means to do this as far as I'm aware, but there should be no harm in calling the unmanaged method.

Comment: Its every now and again, for every Job the application process, required to clean the recycle bin which transferred the files on delete actions inside. But I wondered, why there is no managed code for this !!